# (nodejs webpack) A waste bundling all jsx files?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, pug

I got a lot of .jsx files and static .pug (formerly known as jade) files. In every one of these I typically have around one or two .jsx files that I need to use but before I can use them I will have to compile them first. I choose webpack for this job.

Now, compiling all of my .jsx and .js files into one big bundle and loading that one enormous file into each of my .pug files, only to use a tiny bit of it, sounds like a huge waste.

Have I missed the point or is it really how it is intended?

*I get the point that it is going to get minified and all that but it still sounds like one big wastage.*

Comment: `Have I missed the point`  Yes, you use entry points.. then you have multiple files instead of one huge one.

Comment: (stupid question:) Should I bundle the 'ReactDOM.render()' part?

Comment: What you bundle is totally up to you, personally I would use the pre-compiled React js files, and only bundle my own stuff.  But there is nothing stopping you bundle React too, but one side effect is webpack compile times will slow down a fair bit.